# PostgreSQL comparing null values in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, compare, coalesce

when I wrote a case statement to compare values in tables, it came unstuck with variables that are null. It thinks they are different (note: col1 is a character field).

```
select a.id,
       a.col1 as a_col1,
       b.col1 as b.col1,
       case when a.col1=b.col1 then 0 else 1 end as chk_col1
from   tablea a,
       tableb b
where a.id=b.id;
```

... chk_col1 is always 0 when both col1's are null. I've tried

```
coalesce(a.col1,'null') as coalesce(b.col1,'null')
```

but this didn't work either. It still returned 1 for chk_col1.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports the null-safe comparison `operator is not distinct from`.  So, try this:

```
select a.id,
       a.col1 as a_col1,
       b.col1 as b.col1,
       (case when a.col1 is not distinct from b.col1 then 0 else 1 end) as chk_col1
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Personally, I would leave the value as a boolean:

```
select a.id, a.col1 as a_col1, b.col1 as b.col1,
       (a.col1 is distinct from b.col1) as chk_col1
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Also note that I used proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION! :
The variable referenced in the colaesce function must be the calculated one, i.e.

```
coalesce(a_col1,'null') as coalesce(b_col1,'null')
```

Another thing I discovered. Let's say col2 is numeric. The above doesn't work, you'd need to use a 0. Or ... more cunningly, you can use '0', i.e.

```
coalesce(a_col2,'0') as coalesce(b_col2,'0')
```

This is handy to know if you want to generate some code to compare tables by referencing pg_tables or svv_columns. In this code I had 2 tables that I'd created by reading svv_columns metadata table, and I wanted to created a case statement for each variable, so I'd have the two variables from each table side by side plus a check variable which I'd use for summarising later:

```
select '       coalesce(a.'||a.column_name||',''0'') as a_'||a.column_name||', coalesce(b.'||b.column_name||',''0'') as b_'||b.column_name||', case when a_'||a.column_name||'=b_'||b.column_name||' then 0 else 1 end as chk_'||a.column_name||','
from   tbl_a_vars a,
       tbl_b_vars b
where a.column_name=b.column_name;
```

Comment: Note: the above doesn't work for date/time fields unfortunately.